# Using XML Schema how do I  define an attribute and restrict text?

Tags: xml, xsd, complextype

From this example:

```
<cost isoCode="GBP">27.45</cost>
```

How would I define the attribute type and restrict '27.45' to a float type?

I've been attempting with a mixed ComplexType but not had any luck!

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest to never use float and such for monetary values; instead use a decimal or a whole number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `xs:simpleContent`. Below is the starting point.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

    <xs:element name="cost">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:float">
                    <xs:attribute name="isoCode" type="isoCodeType" />
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="isoCodeType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="GBP" />
            <xs:enumeration value="other" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```